# If integral is the continuous version of sum, what's the continuous version of product?

Tags: calculus

$\sum$ is a sum over discrete/countable objects, while $\int$ is a ``sum" over a continuum/uncountable objects. Is there some way to extend $\prod$ which is a product over discrete/countable objects similarly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral

Comment: A product is just the exponential of a sum of logarithms; that fact allows us to transfer just about everything related to sums (including integrals) into an analogue for products.